# jquery stopPropagation problem with live method

Tags: jquery

Jquery stopPropagation method dosen't work with live method. Below the code is works fine  with click instead of live method. Any help greatly appreciated.

### Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Jquery Propagation and preventDetauls Example for Popup</title>
<style type="text/css">
 .icon.white{background:#FFFFFF;}
 .icon{-moz-border-radius:2px 2px 2px 2px;-moz-box-shadow:0 1px 2px #EAEDF4;background-color:#FFFFFF;border:1px solid #E4E8F1;float:left;margin:0 1% 1% 0;text-align:center;}
 .iconlinks{height:20px;}
 .info{float:right;}
 .icon a.infolink, .downloadlinks a, .iconza a.changecolor {color:#718DB5;display:block;font-size:10px;padding:4px 7px;text-decoration:none;}
 .icon .infolink {background-image:url(images/dwn-arrow.gif);background-position:35px center;background-repeat:no-repeat;padding-right:17px !important;position:relative;}
 .downloadlinks{float:left;width:130px;overflow:hidden;}
 .downloadlinks a{float:left;}
 .infolink:hover{background-image:url(images/arrow-white.gif);}
 .infolink:hover{background-color: #1f75cc;color: white !important;text-decoration: none !important;}
 .infolink.selected{z-index: 100;color: white !important;background-color: #1f75cc !important;background-image: url(images/arrow-white.gif) !important;}
 .icon-image{border:0px;}
 .service-name{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:24px;color:#74767A;margin:3px;text-align:left;}
 .describe-icons{position:absolute;right:2px;bottom:2px;}
 .infomenu{text-align:left;margin-left:-150px;margin-top:-1px;position:absolute;width:260px;-moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 5px #2F3B4A;background-color:#FFFFFF;border:2px solid #1F75CC;z-index:50;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
  $(document).click(function(){
   $("a.infolink").removeClass("selected");
   $("div.infomenu").hide();
  });
  $("a.infolink").live("click",function(e){
   $("a.infolink").removeClass("selected");
   $("div.infomenu").hide();
   $(this).addClass("selected");
   $(this).next().show();
   e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $("div.infomenu").live("click",function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   //e.preventDefault();
  });
  $("input.clickme").click(function(e){
   alert("I am fired");
  });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tserviceslist" style="margin:25px;">         
 <div style="height: 178px; width: 178px;" id="icon-12608" class="icon white">            
  <div class="iconlinks">    
   <div class="info">
    <a href="#" class="infolink"  title="Click here to see more information about this Services." rel="nofollow">INFO</a>              
    <div id="infomenu-12608" class="infomenu" style="display: none;"><input type="button" value="clickme" class="clickme" />Information will come here</div>
   </div>
   <div class="downloadlinks">
    <h3 class="service-name">Cricket</h3>            
   </div>
  </div>
  <br />

 </div>        


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanking you,
sureace.

Comment: PLEASE format your code. You can select all your code and hit Ctrl+K in the StackOverflow editor, or just simply indent by four spaces, to get code.

Comment: +1 for the good question, though. I think this is one thing that isn't well-understood by many jQuery users.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just need to change the order of your handlers a bit, and use/check for propagation stopping, like this:

```
$("a.infolink").live("click",function(e){
    $("a.infolink").removeClass("selected");
    $("div.infomenu").hide();
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $(this).next().show();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$("div.infomenu").live("click",function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function(e){
    if(e.isPropagationStopped()) return;  //important, check for it!
    $("a.infolink").removeClass("selected");
    $("div.infomenu").hide();
});
$("input.clickme").click(function(e){
    alert("I am fired");
});​
```

[Give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/WL3ts/), there are a few important points to keep in mind:

- [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) handlers are on `document`
- Event handlers execute in the order they were bound to any given element

You need to stop *and check* the propagation since we're at the same level.  [`.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) would prevent the bubbling from going any higher but that doesn't matter, it's *at the same level* in the DOM, so you need to check if it was stopped, using [`.isPropagationStopped()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.isPropagationStopped/).  Also, since the handlers fire in order, you need to bind that `document.onclick` *after* your other event handlers, otherwise it'll execute first, before the others tried to stop propagation.

Comment: +1 - I had forgotten about `.isPropagationStopped()`. I was about to suggest a fragile solution that tested the `e.target`. Yours is much nicer. (FYI, you have a typo. Look at your first `e.stopPropagation()`) :o)

Comment: @patrick - Fixed, thanks :) I was initially thinking Immediate for consistency here, but it's not really necessary, didn't get all of the "Immediate"s out of there :)

Comment: @user400091 - Welcome :) Remember to accept answers to questions via the checkmark beside the one that helped :)

Answer (score 2):

That is because `.live()` *relies* on event propagation.

The event is not actually placed on the element, but rather on the root node. The event then bubbles up to that node, checks the selector to see if it has a match, and fires if so.

Because the event isn't fired until it is already at the top of the hierarchy, there's no propagation left to stop.

Comment: Hi,
    Thanks for your quick response. But i couldn't get it how to implement. Can u tell me where should i change my code.

Comment: @user - See Nick's answer. He has a good solution that uses `e.isPropagationStopped()` to check to see if you stopped propagation.

Comment: @user - Are you sure you need `.live()`? Are the elements being added dynamically to the page, or are they there when the page loads? If they exist when the page loads, then don't use `.live()`. Use `.bind()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had no problems using pure javascript for the same. Though this doesn't relate to OP's question(looks complicated) just posting this answer for others who prefers JS over jQuery

**HTML:**

```
<div class="ac_results">
<ul>
    <li class=""><span class="chkfix">
        <input type="checkbox" value="ABCD" name="sug_0" id="sug_0"><label for="sug_0">ABCD</label></span>
   </li>
   <li class=""><span class="chkfix">
        <input type="checkbox" value="abc" name="sug_1" id="sug_1"><label for="sug_1">abc</labe></span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".ac_results li").live('click', function() {
   alert('li called')
});

$(".ac_results li input[type='checkbox']").live('click', function(e) {        
   e.stopPropagation();            //does not work
   alert('check box called');
});
```

**Javascript:**

```
//get child elements
var checkbox = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i=0;i<checkbox.length;i++){ 
     checkbox[i].onclick = callCheck; 
}
//get parent element
var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for(var j=0;j<li.length;j++){ 
     li[j].onclick = liClick; 
}

function liClick(e){ 
    alert('list item clicked'); 
}
//stop the event propagation to parent elements
function callCheck(e){ 
    e.stopPropagation(); 
    alert('checkbox clicked'); 
}
```

```js
var checkbox = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
  checkbox[i].onclick = callCheck;
}
var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var j = 0; j < li.length; j++) {
  li[j].onclick = liClick;
}

function liClick(e) {
  alert('list item clicked');
}

function callCheck(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('checkbox clicked');
}
```

```html
<div class="ac_results">
  <ul>
    <li class=""><span class="chkfix">
            <input type="checkbox" value="ABCD" name="sug_0" id="sug_0"><label for="sug_0">ABCD</label></span>
    </li>
    <li class=""><span class="chkfix"><input type="checkbox" value="abc" name="sug_1" id="sug_1"><label for="sug_1">abc</label></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```