# jquery live click event stopPropagation

Tags: event-handling, live, jquery, stoppropagation

I have a dropdown menu which contains a input and several buttons. The dropdown should hide when I click one of the buttons or somewhere else, but don't hide when keypress on the input. I use the following code, it doesn't work. Though it works when I use

```
$('.dropdown input').click(function(e){

})
```

instead of `live`.

But I do need `live`, so is there any solution for this?

```
/*  dropdown menu   */
$('.dropdown input').live('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function(e){
    if(e.isPropagationStopped()) return;  //important, check for it!
});
```

Comment: could you post the html as well? FYI - `.live()` has been deprecated in jquery 1.7, I recommend use `.on()` or `.delegate()`

Comment: is `.dropdown input` dynamically created?

Comment: You should be using on() now btw.  Live doesn't work like click because it is already propagated down to the document level.  It's not stopped at the input.

Comment: You can't do stopPropagation() on a live event because the live listener is applied to the $(document), not the element and therefore the event HAS to propagate in order to reach $(document).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353275/jquery-stoppropagation-problem-with-live-method can help!

Answer (score 1):

`e.stopPropagation()` will do no good for you in `.live()`, because the handler is bound to the `document`, so by the time the handler is invoked, the event has already bubbled.

You should `stopPropagation` from a more local ancestor of the element being clicked.

Since you were using `.live()`, I assume there are some dynamic elements being created. If so, the proper element to bind to will depend on the rest of your code.

---

Side note, but you never "need" `.live()`. There are other ways to handle dynamically created elements.

Comment: @Jensen: If you're dynamically creating elements, you can bind handlers directly to them upon creation. Or you can use jQuery's other event delegation methods like `on` or `delegate`. Or you can do your own event delegation.

Comment: ...if you don't know what event delegation is, then you should read up on it. It's a very simple concept, but extremely useful. The `live()` method uses event delegation, but it hides the fact, so people often don't realize it.

Comment: I am dynamically creating dropmenus. I used the code @thecodeparadox provided, but the dropmenu still hides when I click on input

Comment: @Jensen: Is there a common ancestor that contains all the drop menus? Here's an example using the `body`, but you should use a more local one if possible. `$('body').on('click','.dropdown input', function(e) {e.stopPropagation();})`. When the click event bubbles up to the `body`, if it took place on the `input` that descends from `.dropdown`, propagation will be stopped at that point, so it won't reach the `document`. Again, try to find a more local container than the `body` if possible.

Comment: ...or like I said earlier, you can bind the handler directly to the `input` when it is dynamically created.

Answer (score 0):

did you try:

```
$('.dropdown').on('click', 'input', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

OR

```
$('.dropdown').delegate('input', 'click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**NOTE:** [e.stopPropagation(); is not effective for live event](http://api.jquery.com/live/#typefn)

According to you question ***I have a dropdown menu which contains a input and several buttons. The dropdown should hide...*** means that dropdown is already exists within you DOM. If it already exists then you don't need live event.

Comment: or `$(document).on('click','.dropdown input',function(){})`

Comment: I tried to use on or delegate, but it seems the click event was not triggered, so I use live instead

Comment: @Jensen but live is deprecated.

Comment: @thecodeparadox then this is weird, as I am sure the version I am using is 1.7.2

Answer (score 0):

what version of jQuery are you using?  > 1.7 then:

```
$(document).on({"click":function(e){
  //do your work, only input clicks will fire this
}},".dropdown input",null);
```

notes:
properly paying attention to event.target should help out with overlapping 'click' definitions using .on();