# JQM background click issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, background, click, tap

I've packaged my JQM App using phoneGap (android & ios). It works fine, but shows an issue like a background click/tap event is occurring is some cases.
ie If I clicked on a button in popup window the click is propagated to background button.
How can I prevent that?
Currently i've set an overlay behind the popup and set some delay for the overlay to remove(i dont think it's a good method), but bottom tab bar is showing same issue since overlay cannot be place here.

Comment: I have similar problem when using JQM simplemodal and showing jquery datepicker inside. the "day" click triggers the button below the modal window. i tried different z-index, but failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that, bind the event with the clickable elements to a function when popup window is called. Like this :

```
function callPopupWindow(){
  $('#list li a').bind('click',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
     //steps to do
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
   $('#list li a').unbind('click');//if not unbinded it will trigger one more event with the elements.
  });
}
```

It works in every browser (iphone, andriod and of course in firefox and chrome).

Answer (score 1):

use [**event.stopPropagation()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

[**SEE EXAMPLE FIDDLE**](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

**Showing a `<div>` on button click and hiding it on `<body>` click event**

**EDITED:**

Extracted from [jquery stopPropagation problem with live method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353275/jquery-stoppropagation-problem-with-live-method)

- [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) handlers are on document
- Event handlers execute in the order they were bound to any given
  element

You need to stop and check the propagation since we're at the same level. .stopPropagation() would prevent the bubbling from going any higher but that doesn't matter, it's at the same level in the DOM, so you need to check if it was stopped, using .isPropagationStopped(). Also, since the handlers fire in order, you need to bind that document.onclick after your other event handlers, otherwise it'll execute first, before the others tried to stop propagation.

Comment: my popup window's click events are handled with live event. I've found a document of jquery saying that event.stoppropagation will not work with live event. http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: @muhammedbasil: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353275/jquery-stoppropagation-problem-with-live-method It will be helpful.

Comment: event.stopPropagation and event.stopImmediatePropagation will not effectively work on and live methods. Similar issue I found in adding buttons on jQuery accordion last week. "bind" could handle all these correctly.